# Groovy: replace all values in list with modified value

Tags: groovy

I have a map which contains a list of values. I need to update every value in said list with an encoded/encrypted version of that value.

The map and list could be nested anywhere and I'm just given a path of what to change. For example `myMap.myList.*myObject`

my map of lists look like this:

```
 mymap {"myList" : [{myObject : "aaa" }, {myObject : "bbb"}]}
```

I am given this path :  `'myList*myObj'`

Code to try and update the values:

```
     myMap = [myList : [[myObject : "aaa"], [myObject : "bbb"]]];
     path = 'myList*.myObject';
     result = Eval.x(myMap, 'x.' + path + '="somenewvalue"');
```

This works and replaces all values with 'somenewvalue' However I need to replace  each value with the encrypted version of its original value So of 'aaa' with the encrypted version of 'aaa' and 'bbb' with the encrypted version of 'bbb' and so on.

But this will set all values to the same value. how can I set the values to different ones?

Comment: Can you put an actual example input map and code you've tried, rather than the pseudocode?

Comment: updated to include example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    def myMap = ["myList" : [[myObject : "aaa" ], [myObject : "bbb"]]]
    def theList = myMap["myList"].collect { [myObject: it.myObject.toUpperCase()]}
    myMap["myList"] = theList

println myMap
```

This works to create a version with all uppercase - so if you have encrypt(blah) function you could do:

```
    def myMap = ["myList" : [[myObject : "aaa" ], [myObject : "bbb"]]]
    def theList = myMap["myList"].collect { [myObject: encrypt(it.myObject)]}
    myMap["myList"] = theList
```

I'm sure it could be cleaned up

Comment: Hmm the second line could probably be changed to myMap["myList"] = rest of line and reduce it to one line

Comment: I believe the path is variable; it's unclear if the question is specific or generalized. "The map and list could be nested anywhere and I'm just given a path of what to change"

Comment: Thats easy enough if he knows the path. anything in that could be adjusted-  myMap["${pathToList}"] = myMap["${pathToList}"].collect { ["${objectName}" : encrypt( it."${objectName}")]}  - or some such variation

Comment: Thanks for this, but as Michael says, I am just given a path, so how will I determine how deep the list is to determine where to add the 'collect' etc.

Comment: Can you give an example of the path? If it were me - I'd use the path to grab the list - like in the answer - make the change t, and then use the path to replace the list in the original position.

Comment: actually you are right, I've managed to get it working using something similar to what you described. thanks.